# To compile a bot parser on Aiogram PDF to PNG

Tags: python, parsing, telegram-bot, aiogram

The bottom line is that the bot should download a file from the college's website (pdf), convert it to png and send it to the chat. Calling the command using /get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze7E4.png)
Here is a pdf file that will need to be downloaded to the root of the program and converted to png or any other image file. I tried to convert to png and send photos in an array, i.e. add files that it converts to an array. BUT, if you watch what happens, it does not download the pdf file during operation and does not convert, but as soon as I stop the bot, it immediately converts and downloads the file, I am inclined to believe that this is a crooked paycharm display. And when you try to send photos, it doesn't send them. On the Internet, the solution is based on aiogram 2 using executor. And I am programming on 3.3.0, I ask you to help with this.

```
import asyncio
import logging
import fitz
import requests
import keyboards
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, html, F, types
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.types import (
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup,
    KeyboardButton
)
from aiogram.utils.formatting import (Bold, as_list, as_marked_section, HashTag)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from config_reader import config
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=config.bot_token.get_secret_value(), parse_mode="HTML")
dp = Dispatcher()
dp["started_at"] = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")


@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.answer(f"Hello, {html.bold(html.quote(message.from_user.full_name))}!", reply_markup=keyboards.main_kb)



@dp.message(Command("get"))
async def get_sait(message: types.Message):
    url = "https://lmk-lipetsk.ru/main_razdel/shedule/index.php"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        # Find all links on the page
        links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

        # Assume that the link to the PDF contains the keyword "pdf"
        pdf_links = [link['href'] for link in links if 'pdf' in link['href'].lower()]

        if pdf_links:
            pdf_url = pdf_links[0]
            pdf_response = requests.get('https://lmk-lipetsk.ru' + pdf_url)

            if pdf_response.status_code == 200:
                with open("file.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file:
                    pdf_file.write(pdf_response.content)
                print("File successfully downloaded.")

                # Convert PDF to images
                pdf_document = fitz.open("file.pdf")
                image_list = []

                for page_number in range(pdf_document.page_count):
                    page = pdf_document[page_number]
                    image = page.get_pixmap()
                    image_path = f"page_{page_number + 1}.png"
                    image.save(image_path)

                    # Append the image to the list
                    image_list.append(bot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open(image_path, 'rb')))

                # Close the PDF document
                pdf_document.close()

                # Send all images in a single message
                await bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, media=image_list)

                await message.answer("PDF successfully converted to images.")
            else:
                await message.answer(f"Error downloading PDF: {pdf_response.status_code}")
        else:
            await message.answer("PDF links not found.")
    else:
        await message.answer(f"Error getting the page: {response.status_code}")


async def main():
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Trying to write code following the documentation didn't help. I want to count on your help

Comment: The problem here might be related to the fact that you are using a sync libriary, `requests`, to download a file, blocking any and all code execution beyond downloading that single file.